# Change of components of a vector when inner-product is not defined.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

If a vector space doesn't have an inner-product defined on it, how do the components of a vector change under the change of basis?

If $V$ is a vector space which doesn't have an inner-product defined on it.  $\{e_{i = 1,2, \ldots}\} \ \text{s.t } e_i \in V$ form a basis $B_1$ of $V$ and $\{f_{j = 1,2, \ldots}\} \ \text{s.t } f_j \in V$ is another basis $B_2$ of V.

Any vector $v \in V$ can be expressed as $v = \sum_ic_ie_i = \sum_jd_jf_j $. In the absence of the innerproduct given $c_i \ , \ B_1, \ \text{and} \ B_2$ is it possible to find $d_j \ $ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the question to include more detials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concepts of change of basis and inner product are independent of one another.

If a vector $v$ can be decomposed with respect to two bases as follows

$$v = \sum_ic_ie_i = \sum_jd_jf_j$$

then the way you relate the coefficients of those decompositions is by finding out how the elements of one basis can be expressed as a linear combination of elements of the other basis. Let's assume

$$e_i = \sum_j M_{ij}f_j$$

for some coefficients $M_{ij}$.

Then,

$$v =  \sum_ic_ie_i = \sum_{i,j} c_i M_{ij} f_j$$

But since this is also equal to $\sum_j d_j f_j$, we can conclude that

$$\sum_j \left(\sum_i c_i M_{ij} - d_j\right) f_j = 0$$

Now, because the $f_j$ form a basis, the above equality is only true if all the coefficients are $0$ and thus

$$d_j = \sum_i c_i M_{ij}$$

which gives a relation between the coefficients of each decomposition of $v$.

Comment: Aah. That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: Is it clear to you why all the operations I did are valid? They are in fact the consequence of what it means to be a basis, i.e. a set of independent vectors that can be used to decompose any arbitrary vector in the space.

Comment: Yes I understood it.  Thanks a ton.